# Is there a way to ignore a tag during a search?

Tags: support, search, tag-search

For example, if I search for

```
[javascript] remove all inline styles
```

I get almost a full page of answers that don't interest me, since they use jquery. Is there a way to filter out all questions and answers with the jquery tag from the search results?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

yes there is , just put a minus/dash before [tag]

like this

```
[javascript] -[jquery] remove all inline styles
```

Please read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) which provides this info, as well as other search help.

Comment: additionally, you can add the `[jquery]` tag to your ignored tags and avoid having to explicitly type `-[jquery]` in your searches.