# Option to not include specific tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Say for example I know Java and I want to browse the unanswered question section for the Java tag, but I have absolutely no knowledge about using Java and Android together. It would be a cool feature to add a "do not include" option so you don't have to look through things impossible for you to answer at that time, and you can get straight to the questions you can answer.

I think this would help users get reputation faster and be able to find the questions they can answer a lot faster. So in this situation I would put the "android" tag in the "do not include" section and then browse through the "java" tag and be able to search through questions that do not have the "android" tag. Would this be a good feature to add?

Edit: Whoops this is already a feature. -[tag]

Comment: Or if you prefer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267863/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-a-tag-during-a-search

Comment: @CRABOLO I feared when asking this that it was already possible, thanks.